# what does "c" mean next to a string in vba?

Tags: vb.net

Many times have i seen visual basic code with something like this:

-insert code here- "generic string"**c** -insert code here-

My question is what does the "c" next to the string do?

Comment: I haven't a clue what you are asking and where this occurrs. Please show us more context.

Comment: no answer can apply to all 3 of those tags: they are all very different languages

Answer (score 4):

This really only makes sense for single characters, as it signifies that it is not a `String` but a `Char`. It is equivalent to the difference between `"A"` and `'A'` in C#.

See also here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sx7t66b.aspx